# Java generics type mismatch when using wildcard

Tags: java, oop, generics, wildcard, subtyping

I am trying to understand generics in Java and I have run into some problem. Here is the code I have written:

```
class Superclass{
}

class Subclass extends Superclass{
}

class Container <T>{
    T elem;
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container<? extends Superclass> b = new Container<Superclass>();
        b.elem = new Superclass();
    }   
}
```

This results i a strange exception that I just can't make sense of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Superclass to capture#1-of ?

    at Test.main(Test.java:4)
```

I tried to make some changes. If i replace the commented line with:

```
Container<Superclass> b = new Container<Superclass>();
```

Everything works fine. That makes sense to me. It's just normal generics without any wildcard.

I then changed to commented line again:

```
Container<?> b = new Container<Superclass>();
```

I was surprised that this resulted in an exception too. However I found out that Java guarantees type safety even when using wildcards. I thing I understand why this results in an exception.

But I just can't make sense of why

```
Container<? extends Superclass> b = new Container<Superclass>();
```

results i an error. As far as I am aware, <? extends Superclass> means that I can use any subtype of Superclass in the container. And in Java Superclass is a Subtype of itself or at least functions like it were. I thought that by using extends Superclass there would be type safety and Java would accept the assignment.

I tried researching my problem but I wasn't able to find any satisfying answer. I would be very thankful if someone could help me out I tell me, were my mistake is and help me to understand why this line causes problems.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you had instead written

```
Container<? extends Superclass> b = new Container<Subclass>(); 
  // Clearly should compile, that's the whole point of ? extends

b.elem = new Superclass(); // SHOULD NOT compile
```

After the first line, `b.elem` has the "real type" of `Subclass`.  You can't assign a `Superclass` to a `Subclass`, so the second line *shouldn't* have compiled.

You have specifically told Java to forget the "real" type parameter of `b`.  It's known that it is some subclass of `Superclass`.  But since it could be `Subclass`, and that wouldn't let `b.elem = new Superclass()` compile, it refuses to compile it.

You can only use a `Container<? extends Superclass>` in a way that would work *no matter which subclass of `Superclass` was actually used.*  `b.elem = new Superclass()` does not.

This is normal and expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I got it right, the compiler does only care about the declaration typ <Container? extends Superclass>. It never knows dynamic type. So, just in case, in the next line the compiler stops me from everything that could possibly go wrong even't if it might work? I am still confused about your last sentences. I get why new Superclass() does not work. But Subclass is the lowest of all my subclasses, meaning it had to work no matter what real type I used to instantiate a Container. So why doesn't b.elem = new Subclass(); work? Is this because of what @Maks Verver wrote?

Comment: No.  It's because it could be `Container<SomeOtherSubclass>`.  `SomeOtherSubclass` could be defined anywhere else in your application.  Java does not keep track of things like there not being any other "lower" or "lowest" class.  It would also be bad if your old code stopped compiling when you added `SomeOtherSubclass`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is related to the concept of covariance and the behavior of [Java's wildcard generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) when combined with type declarations and assignments.

Let's break down the different cases you mentioned:

1. `Container<? extends Superclass> b = new Container<Superclass>();`
   This line declares a variable `b` of type `Container<? extends Superclass>`, which means it can hold a `Container` of any type that is a subtype of `Superclass`. However, when you try to assign a `Container<Superclass>` to it, it becomes problematic. The compiler is preventing this assignment because the wildcard `?` represents an unknown specific subtype of `Superclass`, and since the type of `elem` in `Container<? extends Superclass>` is unknown, it doesn't allow you to put any specific object into it (except `null`). For example, you could have a `Container<Subclass>` assigned to `b`, and then **trying to put a `Superclass` object into it would not be type-safe**. That's why the compiler raises an error.
2. `Container<Superclass> b = new Container<Superclass>();`
   This is straightforward and works fine because you are using the exact type `Superclass` in both the declaration and the instantiation of the `Container`. Indeed, you don't need to parameterize the type in the constructor, it will be implied by the variable type.
3. `Container<?> b = new Container<Superclass>();`
   This line declares a variable `b` of a raw type `Container<?>`, which is a shorthand for `Container<? extends Object>`. This is the most permissive use of generics, and it essentially means that you can assign a `Container` of any type (including `Container<Subclass>` or `Container<SomeOtherClass>`) to `b`. However, since the type of `elem` in `Container<?>` is unknown, you can't put anything (except `null`) into it, which is why it's generally not very useful in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do now understand, why b.elem = new Superclass() does not work. But I still don't understand, why b.elem = new Subclass() doesn't work. I declare a variable b: Container<? extends Superclass> b. Now, no matter how i create an actual instance and assign it to b, I think b.elem = new Subclass() should never cause any problems. b = new Container<Subclass> and b = new Container <Superclass> are the only options. If it's Container<Subclass> it is the exact typ. If it's Container <Superclass> then b.elem = new Subclass() should still work because of subtyping, right?

Comment: Glad I can help! Answering your question, you're correct! The code would intuitively seem to work because `b` is assigned a `Container<Superclass>`, and `Subclass` is a subtype of `Superclass`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, this is a very common point of confusion.

> As far as I am aware, <? extends Superclass> means that I can use any subtype of Superclass in the container.

No, that's not what it means. It means that the container contains elements of a specific subclass that inherits from `Superclass`, but the `?` means that it is unknown which specific subclass it is!

Perhaps it makes more sense with an example. Imagine that you have your example but with two different subclasses:

```
class Subclass1 extends Superclass{}
class Subclass2 extends Superclass{}
```

And you do:

```
Container<Subclass1> a = new Container<Subclass1>();
Container<? extends Superclass> b = a;
```

This is perfectly valid and will not cause a compiler error: `a` is a container of `Subclass1`, and `b` is a container of classes that inherit from `Superclass` (which `Subclass1` does) so it's perfectly valid to assign `a` to `b`, since every instance of `Subclass1` indeed extends `Superclass`.

But the following would give a compiler error:

```
b.elem = new Subclass2();
```

Hopefully it's now clear why: here you assign an instance of `Subclass2` to `b.elem` which is actually `a.elem` which is supposed to be of type `Subclass1` not `Subclass2`!

You wouldn't expect this code to compile:

```
Subclass1 o = new Subclass2();  // error!
```

So the compiler rightfully rejects your code here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It now starts to make sense to me. Still I wonder if the compiler just assumes that there might be any other subclasses that could potentially cause problems even if there actually aren't any other subclasses? In my example I don't see any possibility to recreate your scenario without adding further classes. I now do understand why b.elem = new Superclass() is wrong but I still don't get why I can't do b.elem = new Subclass().